# Quartz Scheduler runs job every second when daylight savings time starts

Tags: .net, quartz.net

I have an application that clients can run on their machines to download data from us on a given schedule. When daylight savings started, jobs that were scheduled to run once an hour started running every second or more. The only way to fix the client was to restart the scheduler. According to the Quartz documentation, the scheduler should handle daylight savings time. We don't have an issue with day light savings ending in the fall. I have not been able to recreate the issue locally by changing my clock. Here is a sample of my trigger factory that creates the trigger.

```
trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
                        .WithIdentity(schedule.Key, exportProjectId)
                        .WithDailyTimeIntervalSchedule(s =>
                            s.OnDaysOfTheWeek(schedule.DaysOfWeek.ToArray())
                            .WithIntervalInMinutes(schedule.Interval)
                            .StartingDailyAt(new TimeOfDay(schedule.StartHour, schedule.StartMinute))
                            .EndingDailyAt(new TimeOfDay(schedule.EndHour, schedule.EndMinute)))
                        .StartAt(startDate)
                        .Build();
```

Comment: Hey Dan - I ran into this too. Did you ever find a solve?

Comment: @MattW I was never able to replicate it in a development environment or find any solution online. We just had an issue on Sunday with this. Our install base is probably around 100 clients. It only affected 3. But it was enough for it to wreck our sql server given the job it was trying to run.

Comment: Interesting, we have probably 10k triggers and this happened to one of them around DST. I am trying to repro - if I do I will let you know :)

Comment: I was able to rerpo this in a console app -- it seems like a bug in Quartz. I added a bug to their discussion tab - feel free to keep an eye on it :) 

https://github.com/quartznet/quartznet/discussions/2309